# change title with a simple button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementbyid

I can't fix this simple problem, I created a simple button and then a title which says "hello" .

If you press that button the text of the title should be changed for another text (any text I don´t care).

If I use jQuery it works perfectly, but I want to do this without jQuery just for learning.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML("hola como estas")
});
```

```html
<h1 class="title">HELLO</h1>
<button class="btn" type="button"> Click me</button>
```

I use all the getElement and more and it doesn't work, it's supposed to change the text.

Comment: innerHTML is not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const chngTxt = document.querySelector("h1");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    chngTxt.innerHTML = "hola como estas";
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<button id="changeText">click me</button>
```

or you can just change your innerHTML to quotation mark

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "hola como estas";
});
```